# Using Ctrl-Tab to switch between tabs in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

is there any way to switch between tabs using Ctrl-Tab shortcut?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be in your settings under Edit->keyboard shortcuts

The default is ctrl+pg down/up

Comment: Yes, but i can't select Ctrl-Tab ... it doesn't do anything.

Comment: make sure you are not already using that combination in either your global system shortcuts or if you are using compiz, it will overwrite it, so i would try to do it there, or just use a diff key-combo like ctrl+arrow right/left(my preference)

Comment: May there is no way to use it with Ctrl-Tab [@launchpad](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/162000)

Comment: I've wired next tab and prev tab to Ctl+J and Ctl+K and it's working out fine. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 21):

The `Preferences -> Shortcuts` menu will allow you to set most combinations, but will not accept `Tab` as an accelerator, allegedly because it's reserved by GTK.

However, as posted [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/162000) there is an easy copy/pastable workaround that will make Ctrl-Tab move right and Ctrl-Shift-Tab move left.  Run this in a terminal:

```bsh
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ next-tab '<Primary>Tab'
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Keybindings:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/keybindings/ prev-tab '<Primary><Shift>Tab'
```

Verified working just now in Gnome terminal version 3.32.2-2 on Fedora 30.

Update November 2021:  Still working, now in Fedora 34

Comment: Thank you. It works immediately under Ubuntu 20.04, gnome-terminal 3.36.2. But it kills Ctrl+PgUp, I wanted to keep both :-/

Answer (score 7):

I think this is not possible in gnome-terminal due to GTK, see [bugzilla.gnome.org](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=123994).

However, it is possible with [terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html) which is very similar (`sudo apt-get install terminator`). Once installed I had to manually edit `.config/terminator/config` to get it working:

```
[keybindings]
  cycle_prev = <Ctrl>Page_Up
  next_tab = <Ctrl>Tab
  prev_tab = <Ctrl><Shift>Tab
  cycle_next = <Ctrl>Page_Down
```